# How to preserve the content of an existing file and concatenate content from another file into it using cat command

Tags: io-redirection, cat

For Example we have the following files:

```
$ ls
$ test1 test2 random
$ cat test1
This is a test file
$ cat test2
This is another test file
$ cat random
This is a random file
$
```

Now I want to preserve the original content of `random` and append to it the contents of `test1` and `test2` so that I get

```
$ cat random
This a random file
This is a test file
This is another test file
$
```

I tried the following method:

```
$ cat test1 test2 > random
$ cat random
This is a test file
This is another test file
$
```

Second method which I tried:

```
$ cat test1 test2 random > random
cat: random: input file is output file
```

So how can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the following code:

```
$ cat test1 test2 >> random
$ cat random
This is a random file
This is a test file
This is another test file
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked specifically for a `cat` solution, but here's how `zsh` could achieve the same end result, without having to invoke any actual commands.

```
% <test1 <test2 >>random
%
```

Comment: Yes it is one of the many ways to achieve the result, but here OP intends to know if this result can be achieved using `cat` command or not?